# How to test polling an external api with Minitest?

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, yield

I tried to mock & stub both `BaseApi.authenticate` and `BaseApi::TrackableJob` (which are api requests) but failed.

```
module BaseApis
  class PollTrackableJobWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    ...

    def perform(job_id, _invoice_id)
      BaseApi.authenticate(1) do
        response = BaseApi::TrackableJob.find(job_id).first

        case response['status']
        when 'done' then true
        when 'error' then Bugsnag.notify(response['errors'])
        when 'pending' || 'running' then raise EDocumentNotSentError
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notes:

1. Code related to retry mechanism is omitted.
2. We use [mocha gem](https://github.com/freerange/mocha).

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was over thinking it and `yields` method was the solution:

```
test 'status is done' do
  response = {
    'type'       => 'trackable_jobs',
    'id'         => '0b6ffad9177aeb594ad54af0',
    'status'     => 'done',
    'errors'     => nil
  }

  BaseApi.expects(:authenticate).with(1).yields
  BaseApi::TrackableJob.stubs(:find).returns([response])

  assert_equal(true, BaseApis::PollTrackableJobWorker.new.perform('xxx', 123))
end
```